# How to use the iOS Simulator with Flash CS6

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, ios-simulator, flash-cs6

As I heard, that using the iPhone Simulator in Flash CS 6 is now possible, I was really wondering to test my apps for the iPhone 5.

But honestly said, I haven't figured out, how this should work. So my question is: How to use the iPhone Simulator with Flash CS6?

I googled a lot and found only news, that it is possible now. But no tutorial or similar.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your Flash Professional CS6 to version 12.0.2.

After updated, go to your target setting. You will found iOS Simulator SDK is available to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating an AIR project for IOS? when you create an AIR for IOS it will automatically launch the simulator when you debug you movie. hope that helps! :)

Comment: Yeah, of course I do an Air 3.4 for iOS project. But it opens the ADL, not the Xcode iOs simulator. I'd like to select different phones.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have XCode installed and an updated version of AIR SDK

You need to set the SDK location for the iPhone Simulator:
**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk**

You do this on the General Tab of AIR for iOS Settings.

Now in order to target the iPhone Simulator you need to set the following:
**Control > Test Movie > on iOS Simulator**

Then you will be able to do "CMD+Return" and it will publish to the simulator.
The app will show up on the second screen just like a device would.

More info here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4923535